# Grafana & Loki agents not deployed in Tainted nodes

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, grafana-loki, taint

We are running our workloads on AKS. Basically we have Two Node-Pools.

**1. System-Node-Pool:** Where all system pods are running

**2. Apps-Node-Pool:** Where our actual workloads/ apps run in.

In fact, our Apps-Node-Pool is **Tainted** whereas System-Node-Pool **isn't**. So basically I deployed Loki-Grafana stack in order for Monitoring and for Log analysis. I'm using below Helm command to install the Grafana-Loki stack.

```
helm upgrade --install loki grafana/loki-stack  --set grafana.enabled=true,prometheus.enabled=true,prometheus.alertmanager.persistentVolume.enabled=false,prometheus.server.persistentVolume.enabled=false,loki.persistence.enabled=true,loki.persistence.storageClassName=standard,loki.persistence.size=5Gi
```

Since the Toleration isn't added in the helm command (Or even in values.yaml) all the Grafana and Loki pods get deployed in the **System-Node-Pool**. But my case is, since the necessary agents aren't deployed on **Apps-Node-Pool**  (For example: Promtail Pods) I can't check the logs of my App pods.

Since the **Taint** exists in **Apps-Node-Pool** if we add a Toleration along with the Helm command, then basically all the Monitoring related Pods will get deployed in Apps-Node-Pool (Still can't guarant as it may get deployed in System-Node-Pool since it doesn't have a Taint)

So according to my cluster, what can I do in order to make sure that Agent pods are also running in Tainted node?

Comment: "Since the Taint exists in Apps-Node-Pool if we add a Toleration along with the Helm command, then basically all the Monitoring related Pods will get deployed in Apps-Node-Pool" Isn't this exactly what you want? Or do you want to have e.g. Prometheus running only in the Apps-Node-Pool?

Answer (score 2):

So in my case my requirement was to run "Promtail" pods in Apps-Node-Pool. I haven't added a Toleration to the promtail pods, so I had to add a toleration to the Promtail pod. So successfully the Promtail pods got deployed in Apps-Node-Pool.

But still adding a Toleration in Promtail pod doesn't guarant the deployment of the Promtail pods gets deployed in Apps-Node-Pool because in my case, System-Node-Pool didn't have any Taint.

In this case you may leverage both NodeAffinity and Tolerations to exclusively deploy pods in a specific node.